# How do I make my query using left join to be faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, r, left-join, query-performance

I have three tables: users (id), projects (id_project, owner_id) and followers (repo_id, user_id). I would like count how many followers one project has. I would like to return all user projects, with and without followers.

Where: 
id = owner_id = user_id
id_project = repo_id

I report more than 1,000 users in my query. I did this:

```
 rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "select p.id_project, p.owner_id, count(f.user_id) from users u left outer join projects p on p.owner_id = u.id and u.id in (123, 526, 852) left outer join followers f on p.id_project = f.repo_id group by p.id;")
```

The query is too slow. Could anyone give me any suggestions to make the query faster? Am I doing something wrong?

Maybe, I can break into two queries, but how do I get the result of the first (which are the projects of the users) and add in the second query (where I would have the number of followers of the projects) in R?

I am using R and mysql.

Regards,
Thaciana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes switching to a correlated subquery can speed such queries:

```
select p.id_project, p.owner_id, count(f.user_id)
from users u left outer join
     projects p
     on p.owner_id = u.id and u.id in (123, 526, 852) left outer join
     followers f
     on p.id_project = f.repo_id
group by p.id;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `users(id)`, `projects(owner_id, id_project)`, and `followers(repo_id, user_id)`.

I note that you are not really using the `users` table.  So, this should do what you want:

```
select p.id_project, p.owner_id, count(f.user_id)
from projects p left outer join
     followers f
     on p.id_project = f.repo_id
where p.owner_id in (123, 526, 852)
group by p.id;
```

The same indexes should work on this query, although the one on `users` is obviously not needed.

Next, in MySQL, correlated subqueries are sometimes faster than aggregation queries.  So, you can try:

```
select p.id_project, p.owner_id,
       (select count(*)
        from followers f
        where p.id_project = f.repo_id
       ) as num_followers
from projects p        
where p.owner_id in (123, 526, 852);
```